# No Final Strategy for running Linux container on Windows Server 2019

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, linux-containers, windows-server-2019

I am quite confused with the strategy of providing the Linux container support on Windows. I have Heard alot about LCOW and WSL to run linux container but I am still not sure why they are not providing the support of Linux Container using MOBY VM as in WIN 10 till things are not stable ( ie till LCOW is no more an experimental thing).

There seems to be no fix strategy for the support of Linux containers on server 2016 and 2019. In server 2019 I have no other way except running linux container as LCOW and that is experimental. On server 2016 there is another issue if I run docker for win on it I don't get the support of the latest Docker builds as the new versions of Docker are not supported.
There no solid way to run LINUX container on server 2016 and server 2019 that always works with no issues.

There are multiple threads describing different ways of Running Linux Containers on Windows Server Machine but there is no one that provides the fixed strategy to run Linux Production Containers on Server 2016 and Server 2019.

I completely understand the argument that Linux Container should be used in Linux machine but I have quite specific reasons to have it run on Windows machine.(Client Constraints)

I have enlisted my understanding [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/970802/how-to-run-linux-docker-container-on-windows-server-2019/980454#980454).

Please can anybody help me understand the correct strategy or correct me if my understanding is Flawed.